# Difference between “ils sont” and “ils s'appellent”

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes

I want to know what the difference is between *ils sont* and *ils s'appellent*. One is the part of *être* and other is *s'appeler*. Both expressions mean more or less “they are”. In what way are they different?

Comment: With [*s'appeler*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/je_m%27appelle) it means *They are called* or *They call themselves*. *Sont*, third person plural of [*être*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre#French), is *to be*. Don't you see a difference?

Comment: I really don't understand why this question is twice favorited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, translating the same way in English is almost all these two expressions have in common. The verbs you rightly identified **bear different meanings** (as Stéphane mentions, *to be* and *to call oneself*), both **incidentaly covered** by *are*.

Comment: On a related note, writing [this answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/3301/1514), I have to mention *sont* can be used for *s'appellent* in French too.

Answer (score 3):

*Ils sont* means “they are.” *Ils s'appellent* means “they are **called**.” It is the “called” part that makes the second a bit more restrictive, and separates one from the other.

Answer (score 0):

They are  the same in some aspects but there are some differences,

> Nous avons deux verbes différents ici, *être* et *s'appeller*.

Here is an example:

```
    Ils sont Paul.         --  They are Paul. 
    Ils s'appellent Paul.  --  They are called Paul.
```

There is a group of people who are male and named Paul.

Both of them are same but with a different syntax.

Comment: <DEL>Ils sont Paul</DEL> ne peut pas se dire en français. C'est une construction ni employé ni comprise en français. On pourrait dire au singulier « c'est Paul » (*that's Paul* / *he's Paul*) mais avec le pluriel ce n'est même pas possible. Pour parler d'un groupe d'individus qui s'appellent tous Paul, on dirait « ce sont des Paul ».

Comment: @Laure: Mais on utilise «je suis Paul» et «je m'appelle Paul» alor je pense que on peux utilize ce formule pour pluriel aussi. Merc beaucoup

Comment: En français, au contraire de l'anglais, on n'emploie pas *je suis* pour dire *je m'appelle*, on l'emploie pour s'identifier. Exemple d'utilisation de « Je suis Paul » : « Je suis Paul et lui c'est Pierre ». De plus, à la troisième personne on n'emploiera pas, dans ce genre de phrase, les pronoms personnels *il(s)/elle(s)* mais *ce*. « C'est Paul » -> *He's Paul*.