# Why is the subject at the end in this subordinate clause?

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, subordonnées, sujet

I thought that French language's word order was SVO and SOV (when object is pronoun).

But what's with this sentence (from [here](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9cu)):

> Bouclier que portaient autrefois les chevaliers.

Subject is at the end of the sentence! 
What word order is that? What grammatical rule governs this sentence?

Answer (score 7):

It's called **subject inversion**.

It is usually understood as a syntactic rule which applies after the *deep structure* of the sentence is set, to produce its [surface structure](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/Surface-Structure-term.htm). You may want to look at [this topic about inversion](http://french.about.com/library/weekly/aa110601.htm) part IV. A. Relative pronouns.

In the deep structure, as you know, the order is SVO, and it stays as is in most sentences. The footnotes of the page state :

> **Optional inversion** - Generally speaking, use inversion for formality, avoid it for familiarity.

---

Regarding your particular example, the following sentence would be a simple way of defining the same thing :

> *Les chevaliers portaient autrefois un bouclier, appelé* écu.
>   Or :
>   *Le bouclier que portaient autrefois les chevaliers s'appelle un* écu. ([or](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/difference-between-ils-sont-and-ils-sappellent/) ***est*** un écu.)
>   *Un* écu *est un **bouclier que portaient autrefois les chevaliers.***

Hence the definition you found.

Answer (score 4):

Inside a relative clause introduced by *que*, if the subject is not a pronoun, it's possible (but not required) to place it after the verb:

> Comment savoir ce que *Marie* a pensé de son intervention ?
>
> Comment savoir ce qu'a pensé *Marie* de son intervention ?

It's also possible when the clause includes an indirect object. Especially in the case of indirect object pronouns, these are valid word orders:

> Je n'ai pas compris ce que *Marie* nous a dit.
>
> Je n'ai pas compris ce que nous a dit *Marie*.

Adverbs (like *autrefois*) are free to move so your original sentence could be written either way:

> Bouclier que *les chevaliers* portaient autrefois.
>
> Bouclier que portaient autrefois *les chevaliers*.

Note that if the subject is a pronoun the inversion is clearly wrong:

> Je voudrais savoir ce que *tu* penses.
>
> *Je voudrais savoir ce que penses tu.