# Structure de « que doivent porter tous les Français »

Tags: subordonnées, inversion

Je suis en train de lire les nouvelles et je suis tombé sur la phrase suivante :

> J’ai voulu cette initiative parce que l’antisémitisme est un combat que doivent porter tous les Français.

Pourquoi est-il correct de dire « *que doivent porter tous les Français* » ?
Je suppose que cela est une inversion de la subordonnée. Donc, au choix, pourrait-on dire : « *[...] que tous les Français doivent porter* » ?

Comment: Question posée en anglais ici: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-the-subject-at-the-end-in-this-subordinate-clause

Answer (score 1):

Dans un proposition relative, il est permis (mais pas obligatoire) d'inverser le sujet et le verbe, sans que cela ne change le sens. Ces deux phrases ont exactement le même sens:

> J'aime bien le cadeau que mon frère a acheté.
>
> J'aime bien le cadeau qu'a acheté mon frère.

Dans l'exemple de la question, c'est bien cette inversion qui est utilisée:

> un combat que doivent porter tous les Français

est équivalent à

> un combat que tous les Français doivent porter

Notez que cette inversion n'est possible que si le sujet un nom ou un groupe nominal - pas un pronom:

> J'aime bien le cadeau que tu as acheté.
>
> <strike>J'aime bien le cadeau qu'as-tu acheté</strike> .